# If $y = x^2$, then what is $dy$? (What's the definition of differential?)

Tags: calculus, differential

Suppose $y = f(x) = x^2$. We know that $dy = 2x dx$.

In high school calculus, I overlooked a lot of details and mechanically calculated $dy$. Now, I am unsure how the definition of differential is developed in elementary (calculus or analysis) language. Of course, if we let $F(x,y) = y - f(x) \equiv 0$ and take exterior derivative, then $dF = dy - d(x^2) = dy - 2x dx = 0$, so we have the desired result. However, this exterior derivative is a purely algebraic concept and I feel that a lot of elementary calculus perspective is missing. Here are a few explanations that I remember in high school calculus:

0. Naive approach: $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$, so "multiply" by $dx$ yields $dy = 2x dx$. I am trying to stay away from this approach as much as possible.
1. Better alternative: if $\Delta x, \Delta y$ are infinitesimal changes, then $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are related by: $\Delta y \approx f' \Delta x$. Taking Riemann sum,$
   \int_{[a,b]} f \approx \sum\limits_{\|\Delta x\| \rightarrow 0} f'(x) \Delta x = \sum\limits_{\Delta y} \Delta y$, where $\Delta y = f'(x) \Delta x$. This naturally implies the relation $dy =  f'(x) dx$.

I am satisfied with 1) but it nevertheless fails to address the question: "what is" differential? This being said, how should I understand what differential is?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential $\mathrm df$ of a function $f$ is simply the *linear function* that realises the best linear approximation of the function at a point, in a precise sense given by asymptotic analysis:
$$f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y)+\mathrm df_{(x,y)}(h,k)+o\bigl(\|(h,k)\|\bigr).$$
This definition can be generalised to normed vector spaces, whether finite dimensional or not.

Considering the example of your title, $\mathrm d_xy$ is the linear map of $h$:  $\;h\longmapsto 2x h$.

Comment: I feel that you should explicitly acknowledge that this is only one of many interpretations of $d$.

Comment: This is Cartan's classic definition. Of course, one may want to stick to non-standard analysis.

Comment: Or measure theory. Or differential geometry. And I'm sure there are others.

Comment: In differential geometry, it is also a linear map. In measure theory, it might be called a metaphor.

Comment: In differential geometry, vector fields eat scalar functions, directional differentiate them, and spit out a new scalar function. If you have a scalar function $f$, then writing $df$ is just a declaration that you intend to use it as fodder to vector fields, except you shift it around and say $df$ eats the vector fields instead. At any rate, there are several different, commonly used interpretations, and I think your answer doesn't hint at their existence when it ought to.

Comment: With all due respect, “df” is not a differential because it represents an infinitesimal difference. The difference of terms between “differential” and “infinitesimal difference” is that the first indicates a quantifiable number that is the slope of a tangent, while the last indicates a nonzero number that is too small to be measured.

Comment: @Windsoul: Your notion of infinitesimal difference was formalised by non-standard analysis. My answer is not in this context, and I maintain that  the differential is a linear map associated  to a function under certain conditions.

Comment: This is not what I’ve meant: your notation “df” is not the notation of a differential. If you want to call it differential you should write $\frac{df}{dx}$ and call it “the differential of f function of x”. In regards to mapping, the “$d_x y$” notation is unusual but acceptable because it reads “the differential of y function of x”. Hope this helps

Comment: The quotient is  called the derivative. In the one-variable case, it is the coefficient of the linear map, not the linear map itself. For functions from $\mathbf R^m$ to $\mathbf R^n$, the differential is also a linear map between the same vector spaces, usually represented by the Jacobian matrix

Comment: The derivative is not a quotient but a limit of a quotient. So is the differential. They are equivalent. To differentiate means to calculate the derivative.

Comment: I don't agree with you. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Definition), or Serge Lang's *Differentiable Manifolds*.

Comment: As a geometer, I agree with @Bernard, but I would be more precise: the differential *at $p$* of the function $f$ is a linear map $\mathrm{d}f(p)$. The differential of $f$ is the function $p \mapsto \mathrm{d}f(p)$, which takes value in some set formed of linear functions (usually, $L(E,F)$ for fector spaces or in a space of sections of a vector bundle.)

Comment: @Didier: that's precisely  what I denoted $\mathrm d_x y$ or $\mathrm d_x f$.

Comment: MathJax: Don't use `y\prime`. Use `y'` (or `y^\prime` for which the former is a shorthand).

Answer (score 1):

The Leibniz notation of differential, also called the derivative at x defines it as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}}$$
Therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the differential and represents the slope of the tangent to the graph of the function at point (x,y).

Further unifying Leibniz with Newton notation, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\prime(x)$$

Therefore $dy$ is an infinitesimal difference of y.

When $y\prime$ exists it makes sense to write $$dy=y\prime \cdot dx$$

In formal notation $\Delta$ represents a measurable difference resulted from evaluating a definite integral. To understand this better think in terms of
$$\text{average speed}=\frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{v dt}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$

However, the symbol is used with the general meaning of “difference” for clarity in algebraic expressions. This includes the Riemann sum which despite being defined as limit sum with an infinite number of terms, is numerically evaluated by a finite number of terms, where again $\Delta$ regains its meaning of measurable difference.